# Basic logging with console

Tags: python

I'm messing around with python a bit, and I want to track the date/time of which some events happen.  For now, outputting to the console will work just fine.

Currently, I'm handling it like so:

First, get the formatted date/time wrapped in brackets:

```
def get_date_time():
  now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S")
  return "[" + now + "]"
```

Next, whenever I want to "log" an action, call it like so:

```
print(get_date_time(), "Outputting whatever text here")
```

Is there anything wrong with doing it this way?  Is there maybe a more efficient/clean way to do it? There may not be, it just has me curious.

Answer (score 5):

On every problem; if you are repating stuff, you are doing it wrong.

For your question; just make it a function, something along the lines of;

```
def log(s):
    print(get_date_time(), s)
```

Or for bigger projects, use [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the Python logging module. http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

You can format all your logs to output datetimes if you like.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    filename='/tmp/myapp.log',
                    filemode='w')
logging.debug('A debug message')
```

prints

```
2004-07-02 13:00:08,743 DEBUG A debug message
```

as seen here http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/minimal-example.html

If you wish to formate the datetime, use logging.formatter()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I doubt I'll need something this powerful, but I'll definitely keep it in mind.  Can you set the set the format of the datetime if you wish?  Instead of `2004-7-02`, set the format to something like `10/4/2003`?

Comment: yes, using logging.Formatter(). You can do something like

formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(message)s", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")